# runtime.exec("cmd /c start D:\\temp\\a.bat"); and what is /c are there any other options in place of "/c"

Tags: java

I don't know about this method , but I have a idea how to run a bat file in Java

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

 try {

Process p1 = runtime.exec("cmd /c start D:\\temp\\a.bat");
InputStream is = p1.getInputStream();
int i = 0;
while( (i = is.read() ) != -1) {
    System.out.print((char)i);
}
} catch(IOException ioException) {

System.out.println(ioException.getMessage() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/C Carries out the command specified by the string and then terminates.
to your answer yer there are many

go to your command window and `C:\>cmd /?` you will get below list

```
/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
/S      Modifies the treatment of string after /C or /K (see below)
/Q      Turns echo off
/D      Disable execution of AutoRun commands from registry (see below)
/A      Causes the output of internal commands to a pipe or file to be ANSI
/U      Causes the output of internal commands to a pipe or file to be
        Unicode
/T:fg   Sets the foreground/background colors (see COLOR /? for more info)
/E:ON   Enable command extensions (see below)
/E:OFF  Disable command extensions (see below)
/F:ON   Enable file and directory name completion characters (see below)
/F:OFF  Disable file and directory name completion characters (see below)
/V:ON   Enable delayed environment variable expansion using ! as the
        delimiter. For example, /V:ON would allow !var! to expand the
        variable var at execution time.  The var syntax expands variables
        at input time, which is quite a different thing when inside of a FOR
        loop.
/V:OFF  Disable delayed environment expansion.
```